# populate textfield on selecting dropdown struts2

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, struts2

I have a text `<s:select>` in my jsp page .

Now what i have to do is when someone selects a value from this dropdown ,
i need to call my action class to get some value based on dropdown selection.

Now this value (which i got from my actionclass) should be shown in the `<s:textfield>` below this dropdown .

Please help !!

Comment: what on earth is `<s:>` if this is JSP specific can you please explain what HTML this actually generates?

Comment: @Hawken: `<s:>` is struts2 tag being created by the framework creator to enhance the developer productivity as it provides an integration with the framework.In end these tags will generate normal HTML so `<s:select>` or `<s:textfield>` in end will be translated to HTML as `select` and `text field` tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well all you have to use the power of Ajax.You have multiple options to do this.

1. User simple Javascript.
2. User any javascript frameowrk like jquery,DOJO etc

Bind you code with on-click/change even of the Select tag and send a simple request to the S2 action.you can either use [Stream result](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/stream-result.html) to send data back from the S2 action or better (in my opinion) send back JSON data from your action class and user Jquery build in functionality to parse the JSON data at JSP

user [S2 JSON plugin](http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3/docs/json-plugin.html) to send and receive JSON data from Action and JSP to make life more easy.

Please follow this tutorial to know how to use JQuery with JSON and struts2

- [using-struts-2-json-and-jquery](http://java.dzone.com/articles/using-struts-2-json-and-jquery)

**Update**

You need to do something like this in your JSP code for Ajax and JQuery

```
var selectedState = document.getElementById("selectboxid");
        var statedata = selectedState.options[selectedState.selectedIndex].value;
        var formInput='state='+statedata;
$.getJSON('search/dropDownRenderer',formInput,function(data) {
}
```

Comment: Hey @Umesh .. thankx for the answer ..  its helpful ... but can you please tell me [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/using-struts-2-json-and-jquery) in javascript code how the value will be send to the actionclass so that i can get data according to that..

Comment: @TusharAgarwal:in that code it form has been submitted.you can create a query string like `myAction.action?myData="value"`.All you need to have a property with name myData and its respected getters and setters, S2 will put the data itself in the property of your action class

Comment: i am not submitting the form.. that is why i want to use ajax so that ii can populate the field